# Windows phone 8:How to send multiple value to PHP page by GET method

Tags: c#, php, mobile, windows-phone-8

I need to send multiple values to php page by GET method by passing URL with multiple values
Here is wp8 side code

```
private void Track_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Nearby1.Text) ||string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Nearby2.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
        else
        {
            var buddy1 = (this.Nearby1.Text);
            var buddy2 = (this.Nearby2.Text);

            string attackUri = "http://index.php?lat="+latitude"&log="+longitude"&username=abc&nearby1="+buddy1"&nearby2="+buddy2; 
            // values to pass 'longitude' , 'latitude' , 'buddy1' ,and  'buddy2'                               
            HttpWebRequest request =
                (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(attackUri);
            request.BeginGetResponse(Showtext, request);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `HttpClient` Portable, it's easier to use?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Where does it throw which error? - I do agree with Neil regarding `HttpClient`.

Comment: hmm..let me work with HttpClient @NeilTurner